# What does the Valis symbol in Danmachi look like?

Tags: danmachi

In the [Danmachi wiki](http://danmachi.wikia.com/wiki/Terminology) the Valis symbol was described as a "V" with two lines through it. What does this look like?

Comment: Well, I would assume. Like a V with 2 lines through it.

Answer (score 3):

It looks exactly like how it is described. Similar to the Yen symbol `¥`.

[image: window shopping]